# max within query set

Tags: php, mysql, max, opencart

I have the following code

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE customer_product_owned
   SET quantity = (max(0, (quantity - " . (int)$order_product_upgrade['quantity'] . ")))
   WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$order_info['customer_id'] . "'");
```

I would like the php variable to be subtracted from the value of the quantity field. However if the value is less than 0 i want the value to be 0.

What am i doing wrong here? can max be used within a 'set'? I could do this with an additional query beforehand by first finding out the value of quantity but is there a way to do it in the same query?

Comment: Why `(max(0, (quantity - " . (int)$order_product_upgrade['quantity'] . ")))`, and not just `quantity = quantity - ".(int)$order_product_upgrade['quantity']."`

Comment: @dbf: "However if the value is less than 0 i want the value to be 0."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `MAX` is an aggregation function. You need `GREATEST(0, ...)`
2. Don't enclose numbers in quotes. Just specify them as is, like:

   ```
   WHERE customer_id = " . (int)$order_info['customer_id']
   ```